# Python Unit testing with mock and patch a foreign modul

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I would like to test a class which uses the Serial class from serial modul.
I know i have to mock them, but i don't get it up and running:

```
from serial import Serial

import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = Serial('/dev', 123)

    def write(self, message):
        if self.ser:
            self.ser.write(message)
            return True

    def read(self):
        if self.ser.inWaiting():
            return self.ser.read(1)
        return None


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.mc = MyClass()

    def test_init(self):
        self.mc = MyClass()

        #Check if...
        mock.assert_called_with('/dev', 123)

    def test_write(self):
        self.mc.write('lala')

        #Check if...
        mock.write.assert_called_with('lala')

    def test_read(self):

        #patch inWaiting function...
        mock.inWaiting.retval = 4

        #patch inWaiting function...
        mock.read.retval = 'lulu'

        x = self.mc.read()

        self.assertEqual('lulu')

        #Check if...
        mock.read.assert_called_with(1)
```

- For the complete TestClass: How do i mock the Serial class so that it won't use the real one?
- For some tests: How do i mock the Serial.read(x) with parameter x and return value? (just like Serial.inWaiting())
- For some tests: How do i mock the Serial.write(message) with parameter and then test it for calling with parameter message?
- One bonus question: should i use unittest2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the best way to do it is to `patch` `Serial` class. In your case you imported `Serial` in test module and to patch it you should use something like this

```
def setUp(self):
    patcher = patch("__main__.Serial", autospec=True)
    self.mock = patcher.start()
    self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
    self.mc = MyClass()
    self.mock.reset_mock()
```

Your test should work if you change any reference to `mock` by `self.mock` and `test_read` as follow :

```
def test_read(self):
    self.mock.inWaiting.return_value = 4
    self.mock.read.return_value = 'lulu'
    self.assertEqual(self.mc.read(), 'lulu')
    self.mock.read.assert_called_with(1)
```